# Меняется цвет сначала на черный, а потом на бирюзовый

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы цвет пункта менялся на бирюзовый сразу, но сейчас он меняется на одну миллисекунду на черный, а потом только на бирюзовый.

```
<nav>
                        <ul class="menu d-flex">
                            <li class="menu__item"><a href="#">
                                Главная
                            </a></li>
                            <li class="menu__item"><a href="#">
                                Магазин
                            </a></li>
                            <li class="menu__item"><a href="#">
                                О бренде
                            </a></li>
                            <li class="menu__item"><a href="#">
                                Контакты
                            </a></li>
                        </ul>
   </nav>
```

CSS

```
a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: #6E9C9F;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, white 55%, #F1EADC 45%);
    height: 1000px;
}

.logo {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 51px;
}

.menu {
    margin-top: 56px;
}

.menu__item {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-right: 45px;
}

.menu__item a:hover {
    transition: all ease 0.5s;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.menu__item:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> но сейчас он меняется на одну миллисекунду на черный, а потом только
> на бирюзовый.

дело в том, что ссылка у вас с `font-weight: 400` (нормальный), а после наведения с `font-weight: 700` (жирный)

и изменение состояния надписи происходит постоянно эффект за эффектом

сначала у вас уходит время чтобы нежирный текст стал жирным (это 2 состояния без плавного перехода), а потом меняется цвет с черного на бирюзовый (это уже с плавным переходом)

поэтому и кажется, что сначала долго держится черный цвет - пока он с нормального на жирный переходит

поэтому оставьте анимацию только для цвета, без жирности:

```
transition: color ease 0.5s;
```

теперь остается еще один чисто психологический эффект - хотя цвет и меняется с черного на бирюзовый плавно, глаз долго темно-бирюзовый будет воспринимать как черный, поэтому переход надо сделать чуть-чуть другим

```
transition: color cubic-bezier(0.08, 0.78, 0.53, 0.59) 0.5s;
```

тут надо поиграться с цифрами, чтобы вначале где-то до 0.3 быстро было пройдено изменения цвета, а потом уже более плавно и неторопливо

https://cubic-bezier.com/#.08,.78,.53,.59 - сайт в  помощь

Comment: Спасибо! Но остался один штрих, не могу понять, как его сделать. Нужно, чтобы при наведении font-weight на 700 менялся тоже плавно. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: `Нужно, чтобы при наведении font-weight на 700 менялся тоже плавно` - к сожалению этого не получится - шрифты фиксированы размером и например `font-weight: 451` - это все тот же `font-weight: 400`, и повышая это значение в определённый момент просто произойдет скачек шрифта в жирный. Возможно дело в шрифте, т.е. обычно это только normal, bold, но некоторые шрифты поддерживают и другие значения - но это экзотика. Что можно посоветовать - схитрить, т.е. шрифт нормальный и шрифт жирный, но!!! добавить еще и тень - тогда при определённом размере тени будет казаться, что шрифт жирный - а вот...

Comment: ... а вот прозрачность тени уже можно менять плавно - т.е. будет такая система `нормальный шрифт, черный` -> `нормальный шрифт + тень по центру текста` -> `жирный шрифт без тени` - думаю, что только так можно нужный вам эффект создать

но вообще использовать нормальный - жирный переход не очень красиво - потому что текст немного из-за жирности сдвигается и выглядит это иногда раздражающе

Comment: Безумно благодарен! Приятного вечера :)